# Multiple includes in one model querying

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

sorry about my English.
I want to do multiple include associations within a findOne using sequelize.
When I do separate includes everything works perfectly. I'll contrast below what works and what doesn't.

```
// that doesn't work
const post = await Post.findOne({
         where: { post_url: post_url },
         include: { // this include dont work
            association: 'postAuthor',
            attributes: ['name'],
         },
         include: {
            association: 'comments',
            attributes: ['comment'],
            include: {
               association: 'commentAuthor',
               attributes: ['name']
            }
         }
      });
```

But if I make each sentence separate it works

```
// this work
     include: {
            association: 'postAuthor',
            attributes: ['name'],
         },
```

Again sorry for the English.

In short, I need to make both includes work at the same time. The include inside the include works perfectly (commentAuthor In comments).

Comment: According to the Doc `include` can be an array of association objects.  https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.htm see

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel! That solved my problem, I couldn't find it in the documentation. I'll edit the publication and put it as it was, in case anyone has this problem in the future.

Comment: Instead of edit your question to add your solution, you can self-answer because Stackoverflow is a Q&A

Answer (score 2):

```
      where: { post_url: post_url },
         include: [
            { association: 'postAuthor', attributes: ['name'] },
            {
               association: 'comments', attributes: ['comment'],
               include: [{
                  association: 'commentAuthor',
                  attributes: ['name']
               }]
            }
         ]
      });
```